# PDO like clause not working

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm trying to fetch some data from the database for my search bar but i just keep getting pdo exception error 
Here is the code

```
<?php 

$sh=$_GET['search'];
$s_query="SELECT * FROM tb_name WHERE headline LIKE ?";
$stmt=$dbconnect->prepare ($query);
$stmt->execute(["%$sh%"]);
$fh=$stmt->fetchALL();
var_export($fh);
?>
```

Here is the error outputted:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[4200]: syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE headline LIKE ?'

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: The error is on like clause...

Comment: Can you give the full error message?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Can you show the full error message?

Comment: PDOException: SQLSTATE[4200]: syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE headline LIKE ?'

Comment: Is this just a copy / paste error or do you have code before this where there actually is a `$query` variable?

Comment: I'm using php version 5.6 on my server but all my written syntax are supported in php version 7 also

Comment: No...it is a copy/paste error

Comment: Given the error message you posted, it seems the error is just before the `WHERE`. But in your original post everything seems ok, so what is it you are hiding from us?

Comment: Could it be because my PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES is set to false?

Comment: Cause I read about the emulation off problems with LIMIT

Comment: Thank you ...I found the problem...it is a typo...I forget to put the tb_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind params like this :

```
<?php 

$sh=$_GET['search'];
$s_query="SELECT * FROM tb_name WHERE headline LIKE ?";
$stmt=$dbconnect->prepare ($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", "%".$sh."%");
$stmt->execute();
$fh=$stmt->fetchALL();
var_export($fh);
?>
```

The "s" in `bind_param` is for the type of var. For example, here it's for a string.

Comment: This is mostly mysqli syntax, OP is using pdo - and you're mixing them. That won't work